# triviality of a $2$-sheeted covering map and the triviality of the associated vector bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, vector-bundles, fibre-bundles, covering-spaces

Let $ X$ be a space with a (free and properly discontinuous) $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action and $$p: X\to X/(\mathbb{Z}/2) $$ be a $2$-sheeted covering map. Then we have an associated vector bundle
$$
\xi: \mathbb{R}^2\to X\times_{\mathbb{Z}/2}\mathbb{R}^2\to X/(\mathbb{Z}/2)
$$
where $\mathbb{Z}/2$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by reversing the order of coordinates $(x,y)\mapsto(y,x)$.

**Question:** if $\xi$ is a trivial bundle, can we conclude that the covering map $p$ is a trivial $2$-sheeted covering map? i.e. $X=(X/(\mathbb{Z}/2))\times \mathbb{Z}/2$?

Comment: Note that, if you allow non-free actions, the answer is negative. 
The quotient $Y$ of $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ by the action $(x, \, y) \to (y, x)$ is a half-plane, hence contractible. Therefore every vector bundle on $Y$ is trivial, but clearly $X \to Y$ is not the trivial covering.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Thanks! but this is not a covering space.

Comment: Well, it depends on your definition :-)  For me, this is a branched covering space (the branching locus is the line $y=x$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can conclude that, because the construction
$$(\wedge^2 \xi \setminus \text{zero section})/\mathbb{R}_{>0} \to X/(\mathbb{Z}/2)$$
recovers the original double cover.